# Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled while making HelloWorld

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.shubham</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloWorld_SpringBoot1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>

</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is my RestController

```
    package com.shubham.controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    @RestController
    public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello World !";
    }
```

}

This is my java resource

```
package com.shubham.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication 
public class HelloWorldSpringBootApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldSpringBootApp.class, args);
}
```

}

While running the HelloWorldSpringBootApp application.My console is throwing an error which is Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-04-19 22:56:10.594 ERROR 8708 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

---

```
 2018-04-19 22:56:06.641  INFO 8708 --- [           main] 
    com.shubham.app.HelloWorldSpringBootApp  : Starting HelloWorldSpringBootApp 
    on DESKTOP-O51GA6O with PID 8708 (started by Shubham Yadav in E:\Spring 
    Project\HelloWorld_SpringBoot1)
    2018-04-19 22:56:06.706  INFO 8708 --- [           main] 
    com.shubham.app.HelloWorldSpringBootApp  : No active profile set, falling 
    back to default profiles: default
    2018-04-19 22:56:06.950  INFO 8708 --- [           main] 
    ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing 

  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicatio 
 nContext@4f51b3e0: startup date [Thu Apr 19 22:56:06 IST 2018]; root of context 
     hierarchy
     2018-04-19 22:56:09.828  WARN 8708 --- [           main] 
     ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during 
     context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
     org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start 
  embedded container; nested exception is 
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
     bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class 
     path resource 

 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfigu  ration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception 
  is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
   creating bean with name 
   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration': 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested 
    exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
    creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding- 
     org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': 
    Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/classmate/TypeResolver
    2018-04-19 22:56:10.502  INFO 8708 --- [           main] 
    utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report 
    re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2018-04-19 22:56:10.594 ERROR 8708 --- [           main] 
     o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start 
    embedded container; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
    with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path 
    resource[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfigu 
    ration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception 
    is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
    creating bean with name 
    'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration': 
     Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested 
     exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
     creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding- 
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': 
    Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/classmate/TypeResolver
     at 
 org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefre sh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot- 
  1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(Abstract 
 ApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context- 
 4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh 
 (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot- 
  1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at 
  org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) 
   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
     at 
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.jav 
 a:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) 
 [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) 
 [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) 
 [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE] 
    at 
 com.shubham.app.HelloWorldSpringBootApp.main(HelloWorldSpringBootApp.java:10) 
 [classes/:na]
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
 creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in 
 class path resource 
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfigu 
 ration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception 
 is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
 creating bean with name 
 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration': 
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested 
 exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
 creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding- 
 org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': 
 Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/classmate/TypeResolver 
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.do 
 CreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans- 
 4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.cr 
 eateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans- 
 4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(Abstr 
 actBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingl 
 eton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans- 
 4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE] 
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(Abstrac 
 tBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractB 
 eanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbe 
 ddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:199) ~[spring- 
 boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createE 
 mbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefre 
 sh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot- 
 1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
 Error creating bean with name 
 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration': 
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested 
 exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
 creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding- 
 org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': 
 Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/classmate/TypeResolver 
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArr 
 ay(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans- 
 4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstruct 
 or(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans- 
 4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.au 
 towireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans- 
 4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.cr 
 eateBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans- 
 4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.do 
 CreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans- 
 4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.cr 
 eateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans- 
 4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(Abstr 
 actBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingl 
 eton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans- 
 4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.getCustomizers(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:82) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:72) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:59) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/classmate/TypeResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/classmate/TypeResolver
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.TypeResolutionHelper.<init>(TypeResolutionHelper.java:21) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:104) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:33) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276) ~[validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory.getObject(MessageInterpolatorFactory.java:53) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$ValidatedLocalValidatorFactoryBean.<init>(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:412) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.getValidator(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:369) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.determineValidator(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:353) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:292) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
```

---

Please help me out!

Comment: can you post the full version of your pom.xml . (you may have two different versions of jackson on your classpath, try a mvn dependency:tree to find out) .

Comment: I'm not using jackson.

Comment: Got it ,Solved by Myself !


Go to C: -> User -> username ->  .m2 folder and delete all folder inside it .


Now Goto Eclipse


go to Windows -> Preference -> Java -> Installed Java -> changed jre to jdk.


Re-install maven dependencies -> run on localhost in browser.

Comment: Happy that you solved your problem.

Comment: Right click your project > properties
Select “Java Build Path” on left, then “JRE System Library”, click Edit…
Select "Workspace Default JRE"
Click "Installed JREs"
If you see JRE you want in the list select it (selecting a JDK is OK too)
If not, click Search…, navigate to Computer > Windows C: > Program Files > Java, then click OK
Now you should see all installed JREs, select the one you want
Click OK/Finish a million times